# Does the word "coaxable" exist?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

I started reading Stephen King's novel "Under the dome" and discovered the word **coaxable**:

> Andy was an extremely **coaxable** man, and eventually Claudette had gotten her way.

I cannot find a definition for this word in the online dictionary.

I found a definition for the verb **[coax](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coax)**:

> - to influence or persuade (a person or animal) to do something by talking in a gentle and friendly way
> - to get (something) by talking in a gentle and friendly way

So my guess is that the author meant that Andy is easily coaxed by Claudette.

Does this word exists or did the author invent it? If it exists, why is it not in the dictionary?

Is my understanding of the meaning correct?

Comment: Well, it does now. (I read it as co-axable. Doh!)

Comment: Sure, in English, one can do that sort of thing. There is no academy hovering over us (like in France or Spain). able is a suffix in English.

Comment: If a word is used by an author, it therefore exists; cf. _addiction, bedazzled, dishearten, swagger,_ etc., all invented by an author. "Is the word listed in a dictionary?" is a separate question. (Your interpration of the word is correct! See this entry in the [**Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/able_2) dictionary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your meaning of the word is correct.
The suffix

> -able

is used to mean "*something* can be"

> drink**able**
>   *can be drunk*
>
> wear**able**
>   *can be worn*
>
> coach**able**
>   *can be coached*

by extension

> coax**able**
>   *can be coaxed*
>
> Horses are not very ***coaxable***, thus the saying "You can lead a horse to water but you can't make him drink".
>
> Children are usually ***coaxable*** with the promise of a present or a sweet, many parents might consider this tactic bribery.